# What makes Jacob Rees-Mogg's accent posh?

Tags: british-english, accent, class-based-usage

The accent of the British politician Jacob Rees-Mogg is often described as posh, with many people going as far as saying it is an affectation of his. To my non-native speaker ears, his pronunciation of words very rarely deviates from the transcriptions given in the Oxford dictionary, i.e. the pronunciation used by many other people in the UK. So what is it that makes people so unanimously characterise his accent as posh or plummy?

For reference, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03SiNNYJu3g)'s an interview with him.

Comment: As Mr Rees-Mogg says at the beginning of the interview: *"Class is how other people perceive individuals to be."* Because people see themselves as 'normal', they consider well-spoken people such as JRM to be 'posh'.

Comment: @Weather Vane: I disagree. What he says about class is absurd. People often know what class they are and don't consider myself to be 'normal'. [What does that mean?] Doesn't everything about JRM - the houses he grew up in, going to prep school, Eton and Oxford, being raised by nanny and later employing her as nanny to his own children, boasting of never having changed a nappy, being worth more than £100 million [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Rees-Mogg) - don't these make him 'posh'?

Answer (score 1):

With the widespread adoption of *creaky voice* ('*vocal fry*') we may have forgotten that it was hitherto associated, in the UK, with the upper class and was used to give the impression that the speaker was rather bored, or couldn't really be bothered to speak to you, or that you yourself were overexcited. (Some examples of his creaky voice: 'upper class' at 1.01", the second 'um' and 'yes' at 1'53")

The perceived authority of a deep voice has been exploited by British politicians from Harold Macmillan to Theresa May. Margaret Thatcher went so far as to hire a vocal coach to change the register of her voice. Jacob Rees-Mogg's voice is not naturally deep, so he needs to creak.

Generally his tone in your clip is carefully uninterested. Bored. It doesn't *do* to be too enthusiastic.

Specific examples of posh pronunciation:

individuals:individjorls (30"), they're not:nort (48"),class [nasalized] (49"), never met:never mairt (2'22"), so:seəo (2'26"). The cultivated stammer 42-43", 2'29", 2'55-56".

Comment: But note this clip is an intentionally humorous skit, where he’s overdoing it, almost as a caricature of “upper class.” That may not change his basic accent, of course. There are other clips of his speeches available.  Received pronunciation?

Comment: Of course it's a skit. No - he's not overdoing it. That's how he _always_ speaks.

Comment: While it's a skit, it's a skit where "Ali G" has tricked Rees-Mogg into giving an interview, so Rees-Moog doesn't necessarily know that it's supposed to be funny. He's probably trying to talk in a measured and careful way because of not knowing what's going on, but a lot of it is standard Rees-Mogg.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Indeed vocal fry seems to be used by many people in Britain who are thought of as having a posh accent, but I can't help but think it's more than just that. In the particular case of JRM, many people seem to think his accent is so posh as to be obnoxious, which is not the case with Thatcher or other Old Etonians, eg. I think it may actually have something to do with his intonation. About the words you quoted, I reckon he realised them as /ˌɪndɪˈvɪdʒuəlz/, /nɒt/, /klɑːs/, /mɛt/, /səʊ/, which don't seem to me to be different from the standard in the UK.

Comment: I isolated and looped the words you mention and would defend each of them if I could stomach listening to him again! I lengthened his 'met' as_mairt_ precisely _because_ of his intonation: a downward glissando, typical of his "I'm-bored_with_you" tone. His 'class' may be klɑːs but it's nasalized - a quality that is typical of the landed gentry but which I'm too much of a novice at phonetics to transcribe.

Comment: I apologise for making you entertain such a horribly scary possibility :) I understand what you meant better now.